# xcode Expected Selector for objective-c method and Missing @end errors

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DiseaseResultsViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize symptomTextField;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"searchFunctionSegue"])
    {
        if ([self.symptomTextField.text length])
        {
            DiseaseResultsViewController *resultsViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

            resultsViewController.symptomSearchString = self.symptomTextField.text;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

I am getting an "Expected selector for Objective-C method" error on the 
"if ([self.symptomTextField.text length]) line

and a "expected method body" and "missing @end" error in the line below the "DiseaseResultsViewController *resultsViewController = [segue destinationViewController]" line

and I already checked all my imported files have their @end correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the type of `symptomTextField`?

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *symptomTextField;

Comment: The code listed seems fine to me. Is there something wrong with one of the two .h files included?

Comment: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`

 `@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>`

 `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *symptomTextField;`

 `@end`

Comment: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DiseaseResultsViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *symptomSearchString; 

@end`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was one of the most frustrating and silly errors I've seen. I just cut and then pasted back in the code and the errors disappeared :S

Comment: I can hardly believe my eyes, but this also worked for me. Killed off 8 errors with a cut n' paste of the same code. Must be a bug in the code parser.

Answer (score 17):

In my case the error was reported in the .h:

[image]

But the problem was in the .m:

[image]

There was a typo, I enter a + by mistake.

Comment: I cannot believe I did the same thing, mine was + as well

Comment: I had the same problem. The frequency of this, as evidenced by others' encounters, is so suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

I had same error, I have written "+" sign in `.m` file` by mistake.

After seeking code half an hour, I `remove "+"` sign and error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are too frustrated, just like I was. In my case I had deleted the "@end" from the .h file and that was causing the error. Add it again and the error disappears. Take it easy.

Answer (score 0):

More still in my case it was using the apparently reserved keyword 'connect' in a method declaration. Changing to '- (void)initConnect;' solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLelu.png)

In my case, there is an invisible code (ASCII code 0x08 will not display in XCode) in method comment. The code found in Sublime Text3.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).